# Declarative Jenkinsfile multiple environment vars with the same value

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a declarative Jenkinsfile using the `environment { }` block to set some environment variables.

Let's say that I have two vars `FOO` and `BAR` (declared in that order), that for whatever reason I need both set to the value `nurse`.

Is there any way to reference the `FOO` var when assigning to `BAR`, so that I only have to explicitly set `nurse` in one place?

I tried doing `BAR = env.FOO` and `BAR = FOO`, both of which failed, and the docs don't seem to provide much guidance for such a use case...

Here's a rough mockup of what I'm currently using (glorious repetition in tact):

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        FOO = 'nurse'
        BAR = 'nurse'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out actually, for the second var, you can use groovy's string interpolation to assign the value of the first var, like `BAR = "{env.FOO}"` (note that the double quotes are [important](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/pull/110) here).

Comment: I should note that this approach (really really weirdly) seems to fail if you're interpolating multiple envars -- I had a case where I set some envar `FOO` based on a build param, then wanted to interpolate that into an envar `BAR` which already had the `WORKSPACE` envar interpolated; after I interpolated like `BAR = "${env.WORKSPACE}/xyz_${env.FOO}.db"`, `BAR` was nowhere to be found!